# How to get ALL request headers in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to get ALL request headers to properly inspect the request, but it only returns headers like the User-Agent and Origin, while the original request contains a lot more headers.

Is there a way of actually getting all the headers?

For reference, here's the code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('request', req => {
   console.log(req.headers());
});
await page.goto('https://reddit.com');
```

Thanks in advance, iLinked

Comment: There might be a way by listening for the cdp request events as noted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232903

Comment: Also check out [Headers in Puppeteer are not same as in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336825/headers-in-puppeteer-are-not-same-as-in-browser)

Answer (score 4):

U can use the url https://headers.cloxy.net/request.php to see your headers

```
await page.goto('https://headers.cloxy.net/request.php');
```

U can also print to log

```
  console.log((await page.goto('https://example.org/')).request().headers());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch from puppeteer to [playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright), and then using Firefox (but not Chromium or WebKit) you'll get more headers:

```js
import playwright from 'playwright';

(async () => {
    const browser = await playwright['firefox'].launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.on('request', req => {
        console.log(req.headers());
    });
    await page.goto("https://example.com/");

    await browser.close();
})();
```

`playwright['firefox']` output (on other sites I've seen cookies too):

```js
{
  host: 'example.com',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
}
```

vs. `playwright['chromium']` output:

```js
{
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/90.0.4421.0 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted but you deserve an upvote because this works too well!! Thanks for sharing a code! I wonder how would you use `playwright` to get the body's data as well?

Comment: [`page.content()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-content)

Comment: it gives me an error: `Promise { <pending> }
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

page.content: Target closed`

Comment: `await page.content()`