# Puppeteer - Request Interception Doesn't Display All Request Headers

Tags: puppeteer

Hi I have a Puppeteer that launches the native `chrome.exe` and I tried to intercept a request and `console.log` it's headers.

As shown below in the Screenshot it does not show me all the headers.

[image]

On chrome's Network Tab, I'm able to see all the headers that are missing as indicated by the red arrow drawn. I suspect it has something to do with the prompt "Provisional headers are shown". I'm not really too sure what this means. Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing request headers in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078655/missing-request-headers-in-puppeteer)

Comment: Also check out [Headers in Puppeteer are not same as in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336825/headers-in-puppeteer-are-not-same-as-in-browser)

Comment: @SergeyGeron No sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is an already answered question about how to handle ["Provisional headers are shown"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger) warnings. From here not the top answers but the one that suggests **"Disable site isolation"** chrome launch flag can help.

According to the [peter.sh page](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-site-isolation-trials) it:

> [d]isables site isolation. Note that the opt-in (to site-per-process,
> isolate-origins, etc.) via enterprise policy and/or cmdline takes
> precedence over the kDisableSiteIsolation switch (i.e. the opt-in
> takes effect despite potential presence of kDisableSiteIsolation
> switch). Note that for historic reasons the name of the switch
> misleadingly mentions "trials", but the switch also disables the
> default site isolation that ships on desktop since M67. The name of
> the switch is preserved for backcompatibility of chrome://flags.

It is most likely an HSTS or CORS-related phenomenon, and it is probably safe to disable the site isolation in your case.

Try to launch your puppeteer like this:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--disable-site-isolation-trials'] })
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have this flag already on my puppeteer launch arguments. It does not help in my case :(

Comment: I see. I suggest you update your question with your launch parameters (similar snippet to mine). you can avoid that you'll get suggestions that you are already using/tried.