# How can I get a Request header in a page?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

How can I get a resquest body using puppeteer?
The wanted content is showed in the picture below

Code I have so far: https://sourceb.in/ELxsmbpy0L

Thank you.

[The header I wanted to get (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2cA9.png)

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078655/missing-request-headers-in-puppeteer/62232903#62232903

Comment: It doesnt work, all it returns is `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `headers` of request and response with this

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', request => {
   if (request.isInterceptResolutionHandled()) return;   

   const requestHeaders = request.headers() //getting headers of your request
   //do whatever with your request headers
});
// Opening YouTube.com
const response = await page.goto("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8VYWazR5mE");

const cookies = await page.cookies()

const headers = response.headers() //getting headers of your response
const source = await response.text()
await fs.writeFile('./page.html', source);
await navigationPromise
```

[response.headers()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#httprequestheaders) and [request.headers()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#httprequestheaders) are in the document.

You can have many examples from [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md) too

Comment: I think it is the response headers... but I need the request hearders

Comment: It logs out: https://sourceb.in/ZqcrjlUruP
which is the response headers  But request header are needed

Comment: I modified my answer, you can check it out again :D

Comment: Let me know if you need further info, @YueYue

Comment: Now it returns: https://sourceb.in/JI350dlEj3
Any chance that i can get the `cookies` in the request headers?

Comment: Is it what you're expecting?

Comment: I expect it to log out the cookie string  (at least include it): https://sourceb.in/JTNuuWcMyx

Comment: You can try this `const cookies = await page.cookies()`

Comment: It is in the "Network" tab in dev tools, go to Network and reload the page, find the name with your video ID (for example, i open a video with id `?v=aGb7QRcb-lo`) and the *request* cookies is in there

Comment: `await page.cookies()` returns page cookie not request cookies...

Comment: @YueYue The page cookies are request cookies too, once you trigger a request, it will send all current page cookies to your request body. You can verify it on any website. :D